# Not able to pass argument to curl command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, arguments

I am trying to run this shell script but the value of val1 is not being replaced in the CURL command

```
gcs_ip="172.16.0.81:8080"
run(){
val1=$1
echo "Migration with clickhouse worker thread: $1, batchsize: , consumer thread: , pagesize:" | tee -a log_migr.log result_migr.log
echo "curl -X PUT "http://$gcs_ip/gcs/api/v1/config""
curl -X PUT "http://$gcs_ip/gcs/api/v1/config" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[ { "application": "pm", "instance": "-", "partition": "clickhouse", "name": "migration.clickhouse.workers", "value": "$val1" }]'
}
run 10
```

Comment: You are using `$val1` inside single quotes. No parameter will expand inside `'...'`.

Comment: So what can i do to get this to work??replace it with double quotes??

Comment: `-d '[ { "application": "pm", "instance": "-", "partition": "clickhouse", "name": "migration.clickhouse.workers", "value": "'"$val1"'" }]'`. That is, replace the `"$val1"` with `'"$val1"'`.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858